# Problem with requesting Yahoo OAuth Token in php

Tags: php, oauth

I've been trying to connect with Yahoo's OAuth service using the standard PECL OAuth library for php. When I try I click submit on my login page, the server should redirect to Yahoo and ask the user to sign-in and then redirect back to my site. After submit, I get anthe page redirects to Yahoo but I get an "uh oh...looks like something went wrong" and that's only because the var_dump line (see code below). If I omit the var_dump statement and click submit, the request will hang on my website's login page and won't go anywhere.

I can manually build the url in an address window  per Yahoo's OAuth instructions with the consumer key, secret and callback url (for my site) successfully and it will redirect to the location I've instructed but I can't do it programmatically through php.

Not sure if the php library doesn't support yahoo's service, whether my server is not configured correctly or some other problem.  I will say I've been able to connect to Yahoo's Oauth service in the past- a couple years ago - but I know there have been changes to their OAuth service since and it was a different service that was used.

Code:

```
$o = new OAuth( $consKey, $consSecret,
              OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM );
$o->setVersion('2.0');
$o->setTimestamp(mktime());
$o->enableDebug();

$request_token = NULL;
try {
    $response = $o->getRequestToken( "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth", [my location]);

    $request_token = $response['oauth_token'];
    $request_secret = $response['oauth_token_secret'];
    fwrite($log, "\n". $mydate . ' token is ' . $request_token);
    } catch( \OAuthException $e ) {
        fwrite($log, "\n" . $mydate . 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

The Apache Error Log just returns that the $request_token and $request_secret indices are blank. I've done my best to find the answers from prior posts but haven't been successful.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there additional information that is needed? Appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with this a bit more and decided I wasn't going to use the OAuth Library directly. Was able to get what I needed by using this library:     https://github.com/hayageek/oauth2-yahoo using the following code:

```
 $provider = new Hayageek\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Yahoo([
'clientId'     => [consumer key assigned to app],
'clientSecret' => [consumer secret assigned to app],
'redirectUri'  => [redirect location I specified in Yahoo Apps],
]);


$authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
$_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
exit;
```